# hide a hyperlink button in silverlight datagrid

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, datagrid

Using the following code in my tool.xaml , I get the following datagrid

```
<slData:DataGrid x:Name="Customer" ItemsSource="{Binding ReturnedItemAttributes}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  HeadersVisibility="None" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" MaxHeight="350" MaxWidth="350">

                    <slData:DataGrid.Resources>
                        <ResourceDictionary>
                            <local:HTTPVisibilityConverter x:Key="httpVisibility"/>
                            <local:VisibilityData x:Key="visibilityValue"/>
                        </ResourceDictionary>
                    </slData:DataGrid.Resources>
                    <slData:DataGrid.Columns>
                        <local:ExtendedDataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Key}" FontWeight="Bold"/>                                
                        <local:ExtendedDataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" MyVisibility="{Binding Visible, Source={StaticResource visibilityValue}, Converter={StaticResource httpVisibility}, ConverterParameter=Reverse}"/>

                        <local:CustomDataGridTemplateColumn Width="40"  VisibilityBinding="{Binding Visible, Source={StaticResource visibilityValue}, Converter={StaticResource httpVisibility}}">
                            <local:CustomDataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                    <HyperlinkButton Content="Pdf Link" Height="23" Name="PdfUrl" Width="76" NavigateUri="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"    TargetName="_blank" Margin="5,10,10,7" Foreground="Blue" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </local:CustomDataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </local:CustomDataGridTemplateColumn>

                    </slData:DataGrid.Columns>
                </slData:DataGrid>
```

The above code creates a datagrid as shown below. Please ignore The column1 column2 and column3 headers. There are just for the people goining to answer my question :

```
Column1  column2  Column3
    name    John     pdf
    CustomerID   1234   pdf
    Customer_url  http://www.test.com  pdf
```

I would like now to show the pdf hyperlink in cloumn3 only for the customer_url
row  and hide for all other rows.  How can i achive it. This is MVVM design pattern.  Below is how i want the datagrid to show:

```
 Column1  column2  Column3
     name    John     
    CustomerID   1234    
 Customer_url  http://www.test.com  pdf
```

My value converter code is as follows:

```
  public class HTTPVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
 {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool boolVisbility = (value != null) && value.ToString().StartsWith("http");

        boolVisbility = (parameter != null) ? !boolVisbility : boolVisbility;

        return boolVisbility ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please take time to express you question briefly.

Comment: @Zafar I have edited my original question. Please let me know if its more readable now.

Comment: I am sorry that you have to use Silverlight :\

Comment: Can someone please guide me on this issue

Comment: You created a httpVisibilityConverter, what does it do? Maybe you post the code? When it does what I imagine it does, then it seems like you just have to use it on the content of your third col's CellTemplate

Comment: Hi martin. I added the converter code in my original question. Thanks